# "Failed to parse manifest" when compiling rustc using a locally-modified copy of the libc crate

Tags: rust, libc, rust-cargo

I need to build the `rustc` compiler using a modified libc crate. I cloned the libc directory and made the changes, now how do I include the modified libc in my build?

This is my Cargo.toml

```sh
[patch.crates-io]
# Similar to Cargo above we want the RLS to use a vendored version of `rustfmt`
# that we're shipping as well (to ensure that the rustfmt in RLS and the
# `rustfmt` executable are the same exact version).
rustfmt-nightly = { path = "src/tools/rustfmt" }

# See comments in `src/tools/rustc-workspace-hack/README.md` for what's going on
# here
rustc-workspace-hack = { path = 'src/tools/rustc-workspace-hack' }

# See comments in `tools/rustc-std-workspace-core/README.md` for what's going on
# here
rustc-std-workspace-core = { path = 'src/tools/rustc-std-workspace-core' }
rustc-std-workspace-alloc = { path = 'src/tools/rustc-std-workspace-alloc' }
rustc-std-workspace-std = { path = 'src/tools/rustc-std-workspace-std' }
libc = {path = "../libc"}

[patch."https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy"]
clippy_lints = { path = "src/tools/clippy/clippy_lints" }

[dependencies]
# libc = {verion = "0.2", default-features= false, path = "../libc"}
```

This is the error I get:

```
mahto@hydlnxeng27:/local/mnt/workspace/mahto/rust$ ./x.py build --config config.toml src/libstd 2>&1 | tee build.log
Updating only changed submodules
Submodules updated in 0.04 seconds
error: failed to parse manifest at `/local/mnt/workspace/mahto/rust/Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  virtual manifests do not specify [dependencies]
failed to run: /local/mnt/workspace/mahto/rust/build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/stage0/bin/cargo build --manifest-path /local/mnt/workspace/mahto/rust/src/bootstrap/Cargo.toml
Build completed unsuccessfully in 0:00:00
```

After commenting-out the `dependencies` section in Cargo.toml, I get this new error:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: unresolved import
error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0433`.
error: could not compile `libc`.
```